# Is property `ref` necessary when schema field type is `ObjectId` in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a sample mongoose schema like below:

```
new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
    },
    digest: {
      type: String,
    },
    owner: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  }
)
```

I wonder to know that is property `ref` necessary when the field type is `ObjectId` like `owner` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not *necessary*, but if you have it, you'll be able to easily load the referenced entities. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
Kitten.findOne().populate('owner').exec(function (err, kitten) {
  console.log(kitten.owner.name) // Max
})
```

Without `ref`, it'll just be an ordinary field that contains ObjectId.

Comment: Yes, without ref, you'll need to state the model when populating: {path: 'owner', model: 'User'}.

Comment: This can give you more flexibility if the field refers to different Models.